# CrediMax: The operation couldn’t be completed. (MPGSDK.GatewayError error 0.)

Tags: swift, credit-card

I am trying to integrate `CrediMax SDK:` https://github.com/Mastercard-Gateway/gateway-ios-sdk in iOS Mobile app.

1. I create a session for payment and that is successfull and response mention below

> {"success":true,"statusCode":"200","data":{"sessionId":"SESSION0002791451838N2104331F28","merchant":"E13043***","result":"SUCCESS","sessionVersion":"fb828aee01"}}

But when i am trying to update session its always showing an error

> error == The operation couldn’t be completed. (MPGSDK.GatewayError error 0.)

here is my effort

```
func updateSession() {

        print("session id == \(transaction?.sessionId ?? "")\napiVersion == \(transaction?.apiVersion ?? "")")

        guard let sessionId = transaction?.sessionId, let apiVersion = transaction?.apiVersion else { return }

        var request = GatewayMap()
        request[at: "sourceOfFunds.provided.card.nameOnCard"] = "Museer Ahamad Ansari"
        request[at: "sourceOfFunds.provided.card.number"] = "6071235068******"
        request[at: "sourceOfFunds.provided.card.securityCode"] = "123"
        request[at: "sourceOfFunds.provided.card.expiry.month"] = "02"
        request[at: "sourceOfFunds.provided.card.expiry.year"] = "23"

        gateway.updateSession(sessionId, apiVersion: apiVersion, payload: request, completion: updateSessionHandler(_:))
    }

// MARK: - Handle the Update Response
// Call the gateway to update the session.
fileprivate func updateSessionHandler(_ result: GatewayResult<GatewayMap>) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingViewController.dismiss(animated: true) {
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showConfirmation", sender: nil)
            case .error(let error):
                print("error == \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.showError(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Museer, I'm facing issue in creating the session, which you got successfully. So, can you please help me to how to create a session for sandbox? I have add TEST as a prefix as well. Thanks in advance.